# Не получается сохранить имя и email автора в GIT

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Я пытаюсь сохранить имя и email автора, она сохраняется, но после чего-то выводится == , а не имя и email автора, не знаю что делать, прикреплю фото посмотрите в чём проблема.

Я пишу все как тут

```
git config --global user.name = 'My name and surname'
git config --global user.email = 'my@gmail.com'
```

Comment: Скрин лучше убрать и текстом написать то, что Вы хотите показать

Comment: « Я пытаюсь сохранить имя и email автора» — покажите как именно вы это делаете

Comment: В качестве имени указываете `=`

Answer (score 1):

Для установки имени и электронной почты необходимо выполнить

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your email"
```

В Ваших командах нужно просто убрать символы '='

Вы также можете открыть файл конфига и изменить имя и почту там. Файл находится по пути

```
c:\Users\Ваше_имя_пользователя\
```

Там найдёте файл .gitconfig

Его можно открыть любым текстовым редактором. Отредактируйте или внесите туда следующую запись

```
[user]
    name = Ваше имя
    email = Ваша почта
```

Сохраните файл. Всё, имя и почта установлены.

Comment: Спасибо, я уже нашёл после долгих исканий, буду внимателен теперь.

Answer (score 0):

Для команды не нужно указывать знак присваивания. Т.е. в вашем случае команды должны быть.

```
git config --global user.name 'My name and surname'
git config --global user.email 'my@gmail.com'
```

Cимвол **=** не нужен. Видимо в вашем случае этот символ ставится как значение параметра. А все остальное игнорируется.

Comment: Спасибо, за помощь. Такая мелочь =, а я весь интернет облапал чтоб найти эту ошибку, оказывается все просто.